# _.chain - underscore JS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This code works fine

```
var arr = _.range(1,1000);
var parse = _.filter(arr, function(num) {return num%3===0 || num%5===0});
var sum = _.reduce(parse, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0) //233168
```

Is it possible to use the _.chain() function to clean this code up? I've tried to code below, but it gives a Type error.

```
var arr = _.range(1,1000);
var sum = _.chain(arr)
        .filter(arr, function(num) {return num%3===0 || num%5===0})
        .reduce(arr, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0)
        .value();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to remove the first argument (`arr`) from each of the functions you have inside the `_.chain()` and `_.value()` (as they are now gather from the chain):

```
var arr = _.range(1,1000);
var sum = _.chain(arr)
    .filter(function(num) {return num%3===0 || num%5===0})
    .reduce(function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0)
    .value();
```

And you could also do it a little more concise, by splitting the `range arguments` (i.e. `1` and `1000`) between the `chain` function and the `range` function:

```
var sum = _.chain(1).range(1000)
    .filter(function(num) {return num%3===0 || num%5===0})
    .reduce(function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0)
    .value();
```

It works, but I'm not sure if this last one is a good idea in terms of code readability.

Answer (score 0):

This works and is (IMHO) a little clearer.

```
var sum = _(_.range(1000)).chain()
          .filter(function (x) { return (x % 3 === 0  ||  x % 5 === 0) })
          .reduce(function (sum, x) { return sum + x }, 0)
          .value();    /* try chaining range() and reduce() */
```

I'm assuming it's OK to solve JavaScript koans here?